# Send GSuite email in Laravel

Tags: laravel, gmail

I have an Google GSuite account: `alert@mydomain.com`, I already setup `Less secure apps` for it.

My config in Laravel:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=alert@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

but it throws:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "alert@mydomain.com" using 3 possible authenticators.
Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535",
with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. ....
```

If I changed MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD to normal Gmail account (ex: `alert@gmail.com`), then email can send normal.

I do not know what's wrong for config in GSuite account. Please help me. Thank you.

### I've found the solution follow this step:

1. Turn on 2fa
2. Create App password (use app password for MAIL_PASSWORD)

Comment: try MAIL_PORT=587 |  
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls | php artisan config:clear

Comment: @QamarRafhan Yes. I've tried to change follow that but still same problem.

Comment: have you tries gamil.smtp on your live server ?

Comment: You mean MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com? I've tried with it but not work too.

Comment: does the user have 2fa enabled?

Comment: @DaImTo no 2fa for it.

Comment: QamarRafhan DalmTo thanks for your answer. I've found the solution:

`1. Turn on 2fa

2. Create App passwords (use app pw for MAIL_PASSWORD)`

Comment: @KiKo you should add this as an anwser on your own question.